How can I change the background color for the stripe payment gateway in the wordpress/woocommerce plugin?
This is my first WordPress website in almost 10 years.  I am a little rusty.  I'm tying to use CSS to alter the WooCommerce/Stripe payment gateway. I can't seem to find the element that I need to change.
The page I'm working on is here: https://anonymouse.ninja/checkout/.  You can view the source there.  I didn't want to copy and paste entire source file.
Here's a picture of what I'm working on. Picture of Stripe payment gateway.
You can see in the picture above I have managed to change quite a bit of the background to gray already. The gray color is just temporary. Eventually, I want it to look like white text on a black background. I would like to know the CSS code to change the rest of the background colors and borders.  I am also open to other ideas that you may have to accomplihs my goal.
One of the main reasons I am having problems is because I am using WooCommerce short-code for the checkout page. That means WordPress writing the HTML. As far as I know, my only options with WordPress are to add styling later with "Additional CSS".
I will be honest, I don't even know what is in the theme's style.css.  I have been using the FireFox "Inspect" tool to find the classes I want to style with the WordPress's "Additional CSS" tool.
Here is the "Additional CSS" that I have added to the WordPress Customizer regarding this part of the site.
    .woocommerce-checkout-payment label.woocommerce-form__label,
    .woocommerce-checkout-payment p,
    .woocommerce-checkoout-payment ul,
    .woocommerce-checkout-payment li
    {
    background: #505050;
    }




I tried and failed using this code for the border:
#payment,
.woocommerce-checkout-payment ul.wc_payment_methods.payment_methods.methods
{
border-color:#505050;
}

I have been going round and round trying to get the black background to work with the Woocommerce plugin. I finally have everything figured out except this last little bit. I just can't find the right code to finish the job.  I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me.
Thank you so much for your time,
Fred

There is a rule with that same selector coming from https://anonymouse.ninja/?custom-css=252a701b0e (isn't that your own custom CSS to begin with?), that sets border-color: black !important;

If you are using the WooCommerce Stripe Payment Gateway plugin, you can follow this guide to change the style of the payment form.
